# set environment variables in next.js

Tags: next.js

I am trying to set the `ENV` in `Next.js`

next.config.js

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
  target: 'serverless',
  env: {
    DEPLOY_STAGE: stage, // How can I set this dynamically when I deploy it at cli
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    if (config.resolve.plugins) {
      config.resolve.plugins.push(new TsconfigPathsPlugin());
    } else {
      config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()];
    }

    return config;
  }
});
```

Now I am deploying my project with this cmd

```
sls deploy --stage dev | sls deploy --stage prod
```

How can I set the `DEPLOY_STAGE` dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also prefix your commands, eg;

```sh
STAGE="dev" sls deploy
```

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
  target: 'serverless',
  env: {
    DEPLOY_STAGE: process.env.STAGE
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    if (config.resolve.plugins) {
      config.resolve.plugins.push(new TsconfigPathsPlugin());
    } else {
      config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()];
    }

    return config;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
env: {
    DEPLOY_STAGE: process.env.NODE_ENV,
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it doesn't work as much as I expected. 
All deployed Next.js projects have `NODE_ENV` that is `production`.